# How can I have a UITableViewCell pre-selected when it's view loads?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working on something that plays an sound when a cell is selected in a table view. The tableView is populated by an Array of NSStrings with sound names.

I have an object as part of the controller that has a sound object, and when you click the cell it plays the sound objects correct file for the name.

How can I have a TableView cell pre selected when the view first loads, and have it so it doesn't play the sound when the tableView first loads.

Here's my selection code as of now.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
TMVSoundCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SoundCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

[self configureCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(TMVSoundCell *)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.soundTitle.text = [[self.soundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]name];


if (self.selectedRowIndexPath != nil && [indexPath compare:self.selectedRowIndexPath]    == NSOrderedSame)
{
           cell.soundTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
           self.itemView.item.sound = [self.soundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [DataManager saveContext];
}

else
{
        cell.soundTitle.textColor = AppDelegate.atmosphere.currentColor;
}


}


#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];

if (self.selectedRowIndexPath)
{

    if ([indexPath compare:self.selectedRowIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        self.selectedRowIndexPath = nil;
    }

    else
    {

        [indexPaths addObject:self.selectedRowIndexPath];
        self.selectedRowIndexPath= indexPath;
    }
}

else
{
    self.selectedRowIndexPath = indexPath;
}

[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `selectRowAtIndexPath` to select a cell programmatically.

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/selectRowAtIndexPath%3aanimated%3ascrollPosition%3a):

> Calling this method does not cause the delegate to receive a
>   tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: or
>   tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: message, nor will it send
>   UITableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification notifications to observers.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `selectRowAtIndexPath` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. An example in **Swift4** :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    if ADD_YOUR_CONDITION_HERE {
        self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .top)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In `viewDidAppear` add this code (in viewDidAppear to make sure your tableView has loaded)

```
UITableViewCell *cellToSelect = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedRowIndexPath];
[cellToSelect setHighlighted:YES animated:YES];
```

Your cell will be selected without calling the delegate method, so the sound won't be played.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
```

method in your viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear and it will select the row and not call your didSelectRowDelegate

Hope that helps

Cong

Answer (score 0):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, check to see if the cell is for the row you want to be selected.  If it is, set it selected.  `cell.selected = YES`

Alternatively, `[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];` 
[self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath];`

Comment: -1 It's the table view who keeps the status of selected/deselected cells. Changing cell.selected will only affect the appearance of the cell, but not actually select the cell as far as the table view is concerned.

Comment: `tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)` in Swift

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.soundArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Sound *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
    if ([obj.name isEqualToString:self.itemView.item.sound.name])
    {
        [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]];
    }

}];
```

I'm such an idiot.  I never thought of putting this in the my conifgureView method.

Thank you to everyone who helped me out.